# @media queries issues. hidden image showing when focus on input element

Tags: css

not sure if anyone can help me here but i am having some issues with media query. so i setup a form and use media query in css to display it on my phone. everything looks the way it should and works BUT when i select the input element on the phone it shows the hidden image. by default when page is loaded it does not show the hidden image which is the way it should work but after clicking in the input element to sign in i see the image in the form. any suggestions as to what i am doing wrong?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){
.login-lock-ico{display: none!important;
 }
}
```

html:

```
<form id="login_form" action="index.php" method="POST">
<div class="login-conntainer">
  <div class="login-lock-ico">
    <img src="images/login/lock.png" alt="login lock"/>
   </div>

<div class="login-form">
  <div class="login-txt">User Login</div>

    <div class="login-control">
      <input class="login-input" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username"/>
  </div>

<div class="login-control">
  <input class="login-input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
   </div>

<div class="login-control">
<input id="rememner_me" type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="remember_me_opt" value="">
<label for="rememner_me" name="cust_email_label" class="css-label">&nbsp;Remember Me</label> 
</div>  
 </div>
   </div>
       </form>
```

i have also re sized my browser to mobile width and it does show properly. just having the problem on a physical phone.

Comment: Please add your html code also, so that we can provide better solution.

Comment: without html, you can try:
.someClass:focus .login-lock-ico{
display: none!important;
 }

Comment: hi guys, i've update my question. Again this works great. just that onfocus of the input it shows the hidden icon.

Comment: .login-lock-ico img { position:absolute;left:-9999px; }.login-conntainer{overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally this should not visible on input focus, but you can try the below one option:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){
.login-lock-ico{display: none!important; height:1px; overflow:hidden}
}
```